# How to increase history in oh-my-zsh?

Tags: zsh, command-history, oh-my-zsh

I just installed `oh-my-zsh` for the first time. I just want to know how can I modify the number of past commands that are remembered in history? Where can I set this setting?

Answer (score 9):

You can set the size of the history file zsh uses with the `SAVEHIST` variable. just put a line in your `.zshrc` (found in your home directory) like `SAVEHIST=n` to save up to `n` commands in your history (replacing `n` with a number of course).

By default, I think that both zsh and oh-my-zsh aleady has a line in your `.zshrc` that assignes `SAVEHIST`, so just change the number to one of your liking.